# egeoxml vs geoxml

Tags: kml, google-maps-api

What is the difference between egeoxml and geoxml?
What i know is both are client-side parsers and both allow me to edit the kml files on the run.

I guess egeoxml is an initiative by google itself and would require the KML file to be at a publicly accesible location which is not the case in geoxml.
Also the documentation available for egeoxml(http://econym.org.uk/gmap/egeoxml.htm) is more as compared to geoxml.

But which one of them is better? I mean Performance-wise ? And an extension to this question is that if i have a website which is public, then there is nothing called locally accesible KML, because even geoxml requires the KML files to be present on the same server where the maps are.http://code.google.com/p/geoxml3/ (Last point in General Notes.)

Comment: You will never be able to read local kml files from a website. This is not supported by your webbrowser,and rightly, otherwise any website could just read any file on your disk.

Comment: Yeah thats true. But then what do they mean when they say local KML are supported in geoxml, because when the site is public this does not really make sense, or does it?

Comment: The only difference between egeoxml and geoxml3 is that egeoxml is for googlemaps apiv2 while geoxml3 is for google map api v3. And since v2 is deprecated we need to use geoxml3.
But what about the above question? Anyone?